# Admob Adview Banner Ad show in Android apps

Tags: android, admob

In my Activity I have used this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AdView adView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(
            "BD9386F17F7DE795B86B5BBBEDDF1095").build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    adView.pause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    adView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    adView.destroy();
}
```

}

in my xml i used this

```
  <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adView"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
     ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-5000769796423780/7961881354" />
```

And in My Manifest

I have used this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

And This metadata

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

I have used this code all the time but this time it is not working.
Even there is no error in Logcat. Recently i used api-21.

Comment: Well, there might be no error in Logcat but still it will say why the ad is displaying probably in a single line. Try to find it.

Comment: Show your logcat. There will always be logging when an ad is requested and when the response is given. You will find your answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the AdActivity to the [manifest](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start)?

```
<activity 
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: Ya I have added this. @rgamber

Comment: My Interstial Add shows fine but Banner Add don't show.@rgamber